# Why does "Barrio" subtheme already include some templates?

Tags: theming

I'm creating a subtheme for Barrio, based on the subtheme included in the Barrio theme folder.
It has already a template folder with some templates in it but, in my experience with other base themes, subthemes don't come with any template override, since the point is that you override only those that need to be changed.

Inside "templates" subtheme folder, there is a "ds" (display suite?) folder with 6 templates that actually are **identical** with the ones in the base theme. And there's also a `_page.html.twig` themplate that has some differences with the base theme `page.html.twig`, but that is not being used because of the underscore.

So what's the point of overriding templates with identical ones? And why is the page template included and not being used?

Comment: "what's the point of overriding templates with identical ones?" To give you freedom on the templates customization if needed. Instead of hacking the base template you  edit the tpl from the subtheme. Doing this you can still update Barrio without worry for your subtheme

Comment: @xaa Yes, thanks. I understand the point of subtheming. But sub themes are meant to add or change things to what the base theme is doing. I mean, if you add a template to your subtheme it's to change or add something, and therefore that template will be different to the one in the base theme. In the Barrio subtheme starterkit there are 6 templates identical to the ones in the Barrio base theme. That doesn't make sense to me (AFAIK, I could delete them and nothing would change and I wonder why are they included in the starterkit).

Comment: The only way you’ll know for sure is to ask the person who made it - but it makes sense to me, why bother writing 6 new templates for a starter kit which isn’t meant to be used as an actual theme? To me it makes more sense to think of the templates as being representative of _how_ to override templates,  not what to put in them

Comment: Thank you, I submitted an issue in the theme page. If they are there only to show how to override templates, I think it doesn't make sense. That info is already covered in Drupal documentation, and including random identical templates in the subtheme, without saying what they are for doesn't help at all.

Comment: Yeah that's a fair point, maybe it's less about demoing how to do it, more about fleshing out a more "full" feeling theme as a starter kit, but also not creating contrived templates just for that. Who knows :)

Comment: I asked the author. In case someone else is wondering: `_page.html.twig` is there as an example of template modification (not being applied because of the underscore). And the identical templates in "ds" folder are there because the author/s of Barrio theme are planning to delete "ds" templates in the base theme (in future update, due to some conflicts) and want to be sure that it doesn't harm any subtheme that might be using them.